# how to create google Developers console projects from the command line?

Tags: android, command-line, build

Is it possible to create *Google Developers console* projects through the command line? i.e., to register new APIs and to create keys for those projects from the shell? I would like to make it part of an automated building process.

Has anyone written some web wrapper for that?

Comment: Not directly what you want but this is somewhat related: https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/ - and try to show that you did some  research in the question. I think there are more related cli  tools like this out there. Somehow I think that it can't easily be done even just because Google doesn't want people to create 1000s of apps automatically.

Comment: very remotely-somewhat connected, did you do some research for your answer ? ;) I think google shouldn't mind when you have a paying account... will contact their support.

Comment: this was a comment, not answer ;) just something I googled and the other thing from the top of my head, I remember having the same issue and IIRC that was something I read somewhere on SO.